# Add element to bottom of container and shift elements up

Tags: javascript, html, css

Hi: I am trying to make something using javascript's `createElement`. I am trying to create something like this: [image: Example]

Currently what I have is working, however it goes from the top down instead of bottom up. My code is this:

```js
 function recal(color, user, content) {
            var element = document.createElement("p")
            element.className = "flyin"
            var spanelement = document.createElement("span")
            spanelement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(user + ': '))
            element.appendChild(spanelement)

            element.innerHTML = '<span style = "color:' + color+ ';font-weight:bold">' + user + ': </span>' + content

            var x = document.getElementById('messagecontainer')
            x.appendChild(element)
            setTimeout(function () {
            element.classList.add('fade-out');
                element.onanimationend = (e) => {
                    if (e.srcElement.classList.contains('fade-out')) {
                        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
                    }

                }
                }, 10000)
            ;


        }
```

```css
        .fadeout {
            opacity: 1;
            -webkit-transition: opacity 1000ms linear;
            transition: opacity 1000ms linear;
        }
        body {
            font-family: Arial;
            
            font-weight: bold;
            margin: 0px
            
        }

        #messagecontainer{
        /*probably something here*/
        }


        .flyin {
            -webkit-animation: test1 .2s linear;
            
           
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes test1 {
            0% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(75%);
            }

            100% {
                -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
            }
        }
        .fade-out {
            animation: fade 2s;
            -webkit-animation: fade .5s;
            -moz-animation: fade .5s;
        }

        @keyframes fade {
            from {
                opacity: 1
            }

            to {
                opacity: 0
            }
        }

        @-moz-keyframes fade {
            from {
                opacity: 1
            }

            to {
                opacity: 0
            }
        }

        @-webkit-keyframes fade {
            from {
                opacity: 1
            }

            to {
                opacity: 0
            }
        }
```

```html
<button onclick='recal("blue","Komali","hello!")'>click me!</button>
<div id="messagecontainer"></div>
```

How can I have it so it goes from the bottom instead of the top? Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were on track, you just need to add `position: absolute;` to `#messagecontainer` and position it left bottom, like this:

```css
#messagecontainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```js
function recal(color, user, content) {
  var element = document.createElement("p")
  element.className = "flyin"
  var spanelement = document.createElement("span")
  spanelement.appendChild(document.createTextNode(user + ': '))
  element.appendChild(spanelement)

  element.innerHTML = '<span style = "color:' + color + ';font-weight:bold">' + user + ': </span>' + content

  var x = document.getElementById('messagecontainer')
  x.appendChild(element)
  setTimeout(function() {
    element.classList.add('fade-out');
    element.onanimationend = (e) => {
      if (e.srcElement.classList.contains('fade-out')) {
        element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
      }

    }
  }, 10000);


}
```

```css
.fadeout {
  opacity: 1;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 1000ms linear;
  transition: opacity 1000ms linear;
}

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin: 0;
}

#messagecontainer {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.flyin {
  -webkit-animation: test1 .2s linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes test1 {
  0% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(75%);
  }
  100% {
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

.fade-out {
  animation: fade 2s;
  -webkit-animation: fade .5s;
  -moz-animation: fade .5s;
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 1
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 1
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {
    opacity: 1
  }
  to {
    opacity: 0
  }
}
```

```html
<button onclick='recal("blue","Komali","hello!")'>click me!</button>
<div id="messagecontainer"></div>
```